# How to move a pointer variable by a specified number of bytes?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

In my code, I am asked to return a pointer to the old value of heap_ptr and move heap_ptr by the amount of bytes_alloc. I have already declared heap_ptr as `void *heap_ptr` and `heap_ptr = mmap(NULL, 2*4096, ...)` to designate 8192 bytes for heap_ptr. My problem is that I am unsure if I am correctly moving heap_ptr by 2000 bytes since bytes_alloc is of type int. Should I cast bytes_alloc like `heap_ptr = (void *)((char *)heap_ptr + (char)bytes_alloc)`?

Here is my function:

```
void heap_alloc(int bytes_alloc) //bytes_alloc is 2000
{
    void *temp_heap_ptr;    //teporary pointer to my mmap heap_ptr

    heap_ptr = (void *)((char *)heap_ptr + bytes_alloc)    //this is where my question is

    return (temp_heap_ptr);
}
```

Comment: You return uninitialized variable `temp_heap_ptr`, I assume you meant to write `temp_heap_ptr = ` on that line.  Also, a `void` function may not return a value.  Please try to post real code , otherwise the answerers have to make a lot of guesses about what the real code is.

Comment: "//teporary pointer to my mmap heap_ptr" - nope, it's a temporary pointer to nothing in particular, because you never set it to something.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic moves by the size of the object being pointed to. So in the expression:

```
(char *)heap_ptr + bytes_alloc
```

the pointer is adjusted by that many `char`s  , which is the same as saying that number of bytes, because `char` is defined as being 1 byte.

The type of `bytes_alloc` itself does not affect the calculation.

Note, you don't need to cast to `void *`, there is implicit conversion. It is a good practice to avoid unnecessary casts to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return a pointer `bytes_alloc` bytes in front of `heap_ptr`,

```
void *heap_alloc(int bytes_alloc, void *heap_ptr) {
    return (void *)((char *)heap_ptr + bytes_alloc);
}
```